# Inverting Amplifier Input Distorted

Tags: operational-amplifier

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax0fg.png)I am building a small project and I used an inverting amplifier to amplify AC signal.

When R2= 220R and R1= 33k, It can work with input signal of upto 600mV but when I reduced the R2=100R and R1= 15K the maximum input voltgae (AC) I can input is 60mV. I am giving an AC signal from a frequency generator(Can there be an impedance issue between the freq gen and my input opamp).

I want to reduce the resistor because of input noise. I can see a good input noise when I reduced R2 to 100R but I don't understand why its clipping the input voltage when I increase the input.

Appreciate if you can help me understand this phenomenon.

I attached the image when R2=100R and when input is >60mV ch1=input signal ch2=output signal, Capacitor value is 10uF
[image]

[image: When R2=100R and input ac voltage is >60mV input signal is ch1 and opamp output is ch2]

Comment: What is the value of the capacitor, and what frequencies are you trying to amplifiy? Keep in mind that the impedance of the capacitor must be less than the value of R2 at all frequencies of interest.

Comment: If you are clipping to only one supply rail, then you need to bias the inputs to keep the output further away from that supply rail.

Answer (score 1):

The gain of your amplifier is R1/R2.  In both cases, the gain is 150, so that's not the issue.

The impedance is lower in the second case.  The opamp has to supply more than twice the current at the same output voltage.  However, even with a 15 kΩ load, most opamps will be fine.  This is unlikely the problem either.

There is therefore something else going on.  Something is not as you think it is, but with the sparse information you have supplied I can only guess at possibilities:

In the second case, R2 isn't really 100 Ω.  My guess is that you found a resistor labeled "100", but didn't realize that actually means 10 Ω.  Ordinary 5% resistors are labeled with 3 digits using a floating point format.  The first two digits are the bare number (mantissa in floating point lingo), and the last digit the exponent.  "XYZ" means XY x 10<sup>Z</sup>.  "100" therefore means 10 Ω.  A 100 Ω resistor will be labeled "101" (10 x 10<sup>1</sup>).

Something is happening to the power supply.  You didn't say how the opamp is powered at all.  Compare the + and - power of the opamp in the non-clipping and clipping cases.

What exactly is it doing when you say it is "clipping"?  Is the opamp output really close to the supply limits in each case?  If not, something else is going on.  Show a scope trace of this clipping output together with one of the supplies.

You were getting more than guaranteed in the first case, and closer to the guarantee in the second.  Some opamps require significant headroom, like the TL07x for example.  At the low output currents of the first case, the opamp was able to swing somewhat into the headroom range, but couldn't when the larger output current was required in the second case.

Again, supply some real data and maybe we can figure this out.

### Added

Now that you've shown a scope trace, we can see that there doesn't appear to be anything wrong.  You are putting in a signal about 70 Vp-p, and your amplifier has a gain of -150.  That would result in 10.5 Vp-p out, but your amplifier can't do that since it is running from 0 and 3.3 V supply.  As a result, it clips.

How is any of this not as expected?

Comment: Depending on the frequency and the op amp, it might also be a slew rate limit.

Comment: My region of interest is 1K-6kHz only. I am using LMV771 opamp.  @ Olin I check resistor and its really 100R (Measure through ohmeter 99.3R) I attached the waveform of input and output signal for R2=100R when the phenomenon shows up.

Comment: @Olin I check the opamp supply voltage(3.3V) I don't see anything wrong on supply. What is distorted is the input signal when I tried to saturate the output, but when output is not saturated(R2=100R) everything works well but I need to see the worst case scenario where opamp start to behave abnormal.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that the signal source, whatever it is, can't drive R2 when it's \$100 \Omega\$.

When OpAmp is saturated, signal source only has to drive R2+R1 ~ \$15 k\Omega\$, which it can do. But when OpAmp is active, the ramp up and ramp down period, R2 is terminated at Vref (because of negative feedback of the OpAmp), which loads the source with R2 or \$100 \Omega\$.

The OpAmp has asymmetric drive capability, so saturates at a lower voltage when positive than when negative. OpAmp spends more time saturated when output is positive than when output is negative. That's why the positive part of the input signal looks more distorted than the negative. The positive part of the signal spends more time having to drive R2 than the negative part. You can see that when OpAmp is saturated, input signal looks like a sine fragment, because then only \$15.1 k\Omega\$ needs be driven not \$100 \Omega\$.

Input signal either needs to be buffered so it can drive R2, or R2 needs to be increased to a values that the input can drive.

Answer (score 0):

> When R2= 220R and R1= 33k, It can work with input signal of upto 600mV

If the input signal is up to 600mV and the gain is 33k/220R (150) then the output signal is up to 90V. Now that's likely not happening so your original belief about your performance is incorrect and this invalidates the whole question.

I would imagine that with +/-15V rails you might be able to see 24Vp-p on the output and with 0.6V (peak) at the input your gain will be more like 20 so, if your original feedback resistor were 33k your input resistor will be something like 1k6.

Comment: During the whole experiment I am checking the dynamic range of input signal so  I start to saturate the opamp by increasing the input voltage(Ac). On R2=220R even I increase the ac input voltage upto the max the output is saturated as expected but when I check what I inputed voltage I don't see the input signal distorted. However, when I reduce the R2=100R and start same experiment when I reached 60mV which saturates the output voltage(expected) but in this condition the input ac signal that I inject is starting to be distorted I don't see a sinewave compare to the first experiment R2=220R.